# Finding the first match - alternative to DomainClass.findAll()[0]

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a shorter/cleaner way than `DomainClass.findAll()[0]` to retrieve the first domain object in the set of domain objects that would normally be retrieved by `findAll()`?

Ideally, I'd like `DomainClass.find()` but such a finder does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use find without a where clause: http://grails.org/doc/1.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/find.html

e.g. DomainClass.find('from DomainClass')

Comment: You could expand this pretty easily in a plugin/bootstrap by adding a zero arg find() to each domain classes metaclass that simply calls your method

Answer (score 4):

How about using [`list`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html):

```
DomainClass.list(max:1)
```

Comment: seth: Since .list() returns a List wouldn't that just result in the code DomainClass.list(max:1)[0]? What I would like is something a long the line "DomainClass foo = DomainClass.find()".

Comment: Mea culpa.  Thought you were trying to avoid returning all your domain objects.